# Per-server rewriterules not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a VirtualHost directive in `/etc/apache2/openpanel.d/www.example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin        "jon@example.com"
   DocumentRoot       /home/openpanel-admin/sites/www.example.com/public_html
   ServerName         www.example.com
   ServerAlias        example.com
   <Directory /home/openpanel-admin/sites/www.example.com/public_html>
   AllowOverride      All
   Allow from all
   </Directory>
   Include /etc/apache2/openpanel.d//www.example.com.inc/[^.#]*
   Include /etc/apache2/openpanel.d//global.inc
</VirtualHost>
```

And I've the following in `/etc/apache2/openpanel.d/www.example.com.inc/RewriteRules`

```
<Directory /home/openpanel-admin/sites/www.stallfinder.com/public_html>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteRule agricultural-show-c780.html /search/event/agricultural-shows/1/ [R=301,L]
        RewriteRule antique-fair-c596.html /search/event/antique-and-collectors-fairs/1/ [R=301,L]
        RewriteRule baby-and-toddler-fairs-c896.html /search/event/baby-and-toddler-fairs/1/ [R=301,L]
        RewriteRule book-fair-c631.html /search/event/book-fairs/1/ [R=301,L]

        # etc... there are ~3000 of these
</Directory>
```

And I've got an `.htaccess` file in `/home/openpanel-admin/sites/www.example.com/public_html`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Search pages
RewriteRule ^search/(stallholder|event)/?$ /find-$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^search/(stallholder|event)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/? /$1.php?name=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

But the RewriteRules in the include file (RewriteRules) don't appear to be parsed/used.

The file is being included because I can put non-allowed stuff in there and apache will fail to load the config file, but if I turn on Apache redirect logging, then I only see [perdir] lines as if all the RewriteRules I've got in the RewriteRules include aren't being processed.

The `global.inc` file is empty, and the RewriteRules in my `.htaccess` file work fine.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not 100% sure if this will actually work (don't have access to working Apache instance to check), but ... try adding `RewriteOptions` directive into your .htaccess -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions

Comment: @LazyOne genius! That worked, thanks very much! Feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `RewriteOptions` directive into your .htaccess to allow executing rewrite rules on parent (upper) level.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions